# What is the meaning of moment<2> in boost::accumulators

Tags: c++, boost, statistics

i worked through this example, but i don't get what the mathematical operation boost::accumulators::moment<2> is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/stats.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/mean.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics/moment.hpp>
using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main()
{
    // Define an accumulator set for calculating the mean and the
    // 2nd moment ...
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::mean, tag::moment<2> > > acc;

    // push in some data ...
    acc(1.2);
    acc(2.3);
    acc(3.4);
    acc(4.5);

    // Display the results ...
    std::cout << "Mean:   " << mean(acc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Moment: " << accumulators::moment<2>(acc) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The example can be found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html

Furthermore, how can i get the distance of a sample from mean in terms of the variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The n<sup>th</sup> moment is the expected value of `X^n`; the second moment is the expected value of `X^2`. It's closely related to the variance:

```
variance = E((X-mean)^2)
         = E(X^2) - mean^2
```

Boost documents the function (including its definition) [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.moment). Wikipedia has quite a thorough article about statistical moments [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29).

> Furthermore, how can i get the distance of a sample from mean in terms of the variance?

I guess you want the distance as a multiple of the standard deviation:

```
distance = (sample - mean) / sqrt(variance)
```